# Multiple nested dictionaries following hierarchy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I've been struggling for a while trying to figure it out to put some hierarchical values in a flat table into a specific dictionary format. The main issue is that I couldn't figure it out how to nest each category inside their corresponding key.

I have this table (as a pandas DataFrame) with the column stating the hierarchy as a number:
The table has three columns:

```
Level    Name           Description
  0      Main               ...
  1      Sub main           ...
  2      Sub sub main       ...
  1      Sub main           ...
  2      Sub sub main       ...
  3      Sub sub sub main   ...
  0      Main_2             ...
       .  .  .
```

And the expected output should be something like this:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "name": "main",
            "description": "",
            "owners":{
                "users":["Sandra"]
            },
            "terms":[{
                "name":"",
                "description":""
            }]
            
        },
        
        {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "name": "sub_main",
                    "description": "",
                    "owners":{
                        "users":[""]
                    },
                    "terms":[{
                        "name":"",
                        "description":"",
                        "inherits":[""]
                    }]

                },
                {
                    "nodes": [
                        {
                            "name": "sub_sub_main",
                            "description": "",
                            "owners":{
                                "users":[""]
                            },
                            "terms":[{
                                "name":"",
                                "description":"",
                                "inherits":[""]
                            }]

                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a large table with multiple hierarchical levels. Sometimes it's just 2 or 3 levels and in others, more. But, all of them are in order.

The other thing is that in `inherits` section, there must appear the parents above them.

I'm trying to build a recursive function but I have failed so far. I have checked these other similar questions:

- [Build nested/hierarchical dictionary from irregular flat dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67387385/build-nested-hierarchical-dictionary-from-irregular-flat-dictionary)
- [Access nested dictionary items via a list of keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys)

Does anyone know any questions similar to this approach? Or if any of you have faced a similar problem?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what the format of the input table is? Is it a Pandas DataFrame? Is it a text file? Something else?

Comment: It's an Excel file but I load it as a pandas DataFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this source dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict( {'Level': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 4, 7: 1},
    'Name': {0: 'Main 1',
    1: 'Sub main 1.1',
    2: 'Sub sub main 1.1.1',
    3: 'Sub main 1.2(a)',
    4: 'Sub main 1.2(b)',
    5: 'Sub sub main 1.2.1',
    6: 'Sub sub sub main 1.2.1.1',
    7: 'Main 2'},
    'Description': {0: 'Sandra',
    1: 'Andrew',
    2: 'Sally',
    3: 'Mark',
    4: 'Simon',
    5: 'Sinead',
    6: 'Holly',
    7: 'Max'}})
```

We can build a tree-formed dictionary that hopefully comes close to what you want:

```
tree = { 
    'children': [], 
    'ancestors': [], 
    'parent': None, 
    'Level': 0,
    'Name': 'root'
}
curr_node = tree

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # new child node
    if row.Level > curr_node['Level']: 
        parent = curr_node
        ancestors = parent['ancestors'] + [parent['Name']]
    # sibling node
    elif row.Level == curr_node['Level']:
        parent = curr_node['parent']
        ancestors = curr_node['ancestors'].copy()
    # ...or skip back up the hierarchy
    elif row.Level < curr_node['Level']:
        # skipping up until curr_node is the proper parent for this level
        while curr_node['Level'] >= row.Level:
            curr_node = curr_node['parent']
        parent = curr_node
        ancestors = curr_node['ancestors'] + [parent['Name']]
    # make new node with given parent & ancestors
    curr_node = row.to_dict()
    curr_node['children'] = []
    curr_node['parent'] = parent
    curr_node['ancestors'] = ancestors
    parent['children'].append(curr_node)
```

Results in:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(tree)

{'Name': 'root',
 'ancestors': [],
 'children': [{'Description': 'Sandra',
               'Level': 1,
               'Name': 'Main 1',
               'ancestors': ['root'],
               'children': [{'Description': 'Andrew',
                             'Level': 2,
                             'Name': 'Sub main 1.1',
                             'ancestors': ['root', 'Main 1'],
                             'children': [{'Description': 'Sally',
                                           'Level': 3,
                                           'Name': 'Sub sub main 1.1.1',
                                           'ancestors': ['root',
                                                         'Main 1',
                                                         'Sub main 1.1'],
                                           'children': [],
                                           'level': 3,
                                           'parent': <Recursion on dict with id=140209092851264>}],
                             'level': 2,
                             'parent': <Recursion on dict with id=140209092850624>},
                            {'Description': 'Mark',
                             'Level': 2,
                             'Name': 'Sub main 1.2(a)',
                             'ancestors': ['root', 'Main 1'],
                             'children': [],
                             'level': 2,
                             'parent': <Recursion on dict with id=140209092850624>},
                            {'Description': 'Simon',
                             'Level': 2,
                             'Name': 'Sub main 1.2(b)',
                             'ancestors': ['root', 'Main 1'],
                             'children': [{'Description': 'Sinead',
                                           'Level': 3,
                                           'Name': 'Sub sub main 1.2.1',
                                           'ancestors': ['root',
                                                         'Main 1',
                                                         'Sub main 1.2(b)'],
                                           'children': [{'Description': 'Holly',
                                                         'Level': 4,
                                                         'Name': 'Sub sub sub '
                                                                 'main 1.2.1.1',
                                                         'ancestors': ['root',
                                                                       'Main 1',
                                                                       'Sub '
                                                                       'main '
                                                                       '1.2(b)',
                                                                       'Sub '
                                                                       'sub '
                                                                       'main '
                                                                       '1.2.1'],
                                                         'children': [],
                                                         'level': 4,
                                                         'parent': <Recursion on dict with id=140209092851520>}],
                                           'level': 3,
                                           'parent': <Recursion on dict with id=140209092851456>}],
                             'level': 2,
                             'parent': <Recursion on dict with id=140209092850624>}],
               'level': 1,
               'parent': <Recursion on dict with id=140209075210048>},
              {'Description': 'Max',
               'Level': 1,
               'Name': 'Main 2',
               'ancestors': ['root'],
               'children': [],
               'level': 1,
               'parent': <Recursion on dict with id=140209075210048>}],
 'level': 0,
 'parent': None}
```

Comment: Thank you @kleynjan! This solution was very helpful to achieve the expected result!